# Excel sort range with a column sequence

Tags: excel

I have a range that needs to be sorted but in a sequence of 3 everytime in a formula.
I have tried seariching for a simuler question on stakcoverflow, but nothing  usefull has come up.
Hoping that someone reads this Q and can help me into a direction

I have tried a basic sort and the sorty function within excel, i have searched stackoverflow for a direction

[image]

Comment: I don't think your desired output can be achieved easily with normal formulas. I'm afraid you'll need a complex solution with VBA or maybe PowerBI but not sure.

Comment: From what you've written it's not clear what your sorting function actually is - I couldn't even do the sort manually with the information provided.

Comment: What happened to the 3rd diameter value? 3.

Comment: @JvdV missed that one, it should be right under the other 2 diameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you happened to have mistakenly missed some output, I think you could use:

[image]

Formula in `A6`:

```
=LET(x,WRAPROWS(TOCOL(A1:I4,1),3),y,TAKE(x,,1),DROP(IFERROR(REDUCE(0,UNIQUE(y),LAMBDA(a,b,HSTACK(a,FILTER(x,y=b)))),""),,1))
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without the LAMDA function?

Comment: @RobertJanKi, possibly, but this is my contribution to your query.